# CSS & Javascript Toolbox: Unprecedented JS Compiler Errors

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

[image: Error Screenshot]

Not sure what is going on here. Compiler seems to be hanged up on semantics. I checked everything in wordpress++ before putting it up on the WP site and it throws these bizarre errors.

Comment: please add your code here..

Comment: i think line 30 bracket is of switch statement bracket.